# Error 500 .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Alright! I've been at this for over an hour, googling and looking around for answers.
Whenever I try to access my page, I get this:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I've been able to locate that the problem is in the htaccess file.
What am I doing wrong?

**Htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^i([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [QSA,L]
RewrireRule ^register$ register.php [QSA,L]
```

By opening the error log, I was able to find the problem, I've mispelled the last RewriteRule. Altough it now gives me a 404 page.

Comment: i think it's because you try to have several files as base, try to go from one file eg. index.php and add the code from there.

Comment: Do you have access to the error log?

Comment: Please open up your apache error log and look at what is written in there. Your rules don't seem to be problematic at first glance. Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: You can put into the .htaccess: `RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log`

Comment: @DanFromGermany That directive can **only** occur in the server config or virtual host context. It cannot be in a .htaccess file. See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: Thanks @Sumurai8, by opening the error log, I was able to find the problem, I've mispelled the last RewriteRule. Edit: It now gives me a 404 page though.

Comment: You created a backup copy of the original file?  If you can take a copy of the original file and perform a diff between the changed file and the original, it should show you the error or misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sumurai8 It now works.

I had mispelled the last RewriteRule